Module 'cloud_firestore' not found in release mode
I tried to run my Flutter app in Xcode in release mode, but I got the error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found. When I run my app in debug mode, everything works as expected. I also uploaded my app to the App Store for TestFlight and when I download it there it crashes, but only after I log in with Firebase Authentication.
I have verified that the platform: iOS version in the pod file matches the deployment info in Xcode and I have verified that I have runner.xcworkspace open. I have also tried
delete Podfile
flutter clean  flutter pub get  flutter build ios
And I also tried the solution from: Flutter (iOS) - Module 'cloud_firestore' not found in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m
But I still get the error and I think this is the problem why my app crashes on the TestFlight.
I am not using the latest version of Xcode, could this be a problem?
What else can I do?

Have you tried doing a pod install as well ?

yes i tried that too, unfortunately without success

Hmm, I've had the same issues with cloud_firestore before, only other thing I can think of trying is checking if it's getting installed correctly. Sometimes it just fails quietly when you run things in release mode, could you try: flutter run ios --release -v. Also if you can do a clean build as well (flutter clean, pod clean) to see how things are getting installed.

When I try flutter run ios --release -v I get the error 'Target file "ios" not found.' and when I try pod clean I get 'Unknown command: 'clean' '.

Ah, sorry. That should have been flutter run --release -v without the ios part. I was combining the build and run commands, and the other command was supposed to be pod cache clean --all, that will clear out the cached installations. Sorry for the confusion, was answering stuff in the middle of the night !

When I run flutter run --release -v I get 'Release mode is not supported by iPhone 14'. And when I try it on a real device it doesn't work because I don't have the latest version of Xcode. And I don't have the latest version of Xcode because my Macbook is too old :( And when I run pod cache clean --all I still get the error.
